# NOVICE: Can you modify navigation items that appear in responsive screen sizes using CSS?

Tags: responsive-design, navigation

I'm looking to remove items in my sites navigation based on the screen size. All of the searching I've seen has been pertaining to the size/padding/etc. 
**FULL SIZE and TABLET MENU**

- ONE
- TWO
- THREE
- FOUR
- FIVE

**MOBILE MENU**

- ONE
- THREE
- FOUR

So far I've been researching all I can on responsive menus. I haven't found anything beyond physical modifications like colors, margins, padding, borders, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand the problem without more reference or a code snippet. From what I get is, you're trying to modify your site's navigation menu based on the screen size by selectively showing or hiding certain menu items.

You can do that in CSS and possibly JavaScript. You can do so by structuring your navigation menu in your HTML code. You can use different classes or IDs to identify the menu items that you want to show or hide based on screen size.

For example in HTML:

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="full-size-menu">
    <li>ONE</li>
    <li>TWO</li>
    <li>THREE</li>
    <li>FOUR</li>
    <li>FIVE</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="mobile-menu">
    <li>ONE</li>
    <li>THREE</li>
    <li>FOUR</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

In CSS:

```css
/* Styles for full-size screens and tablets */
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  .mobile-menu {
    display: none; /* Hide the mobile menu */
  }
}
    
/* Styles for mobile screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .full-size-menu {
    display: none; /* Hide the full-size menu */
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great Bob, I appreciate it. I'll have to do some digging to see where my nav html is hiding.